# при достовании значения из стека в nasm x86 получаю неплавильное значние

Tags: nasm, x86, assembly

у меня есть код на nasm x86 под 64'х разрядную windows10
вот код:

```
global _start
section .text
_start:
    mov rax, 7
    push rax
    mov rax, 8
    push rax
    push QWORD [rsp + 8]
    pop rax
    ret
    mov rax, 0
    ret
```

при его выполнении я ожидаю что %ERRORLEVEL% будет равен 7 но он просто выдаёт -1073741819.
зарание спасибо